# How to retrieve inserted ID after using add() on an Object?

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to create a script that automatically imports a XML file, I got this working, but for a reason I need to get the ID from a category I am adding, this category ID is auto increment, so there is no way I could get this out of the existing data.

So my code looks like this:

```
        $category = new Category;
        $category->active = 1;
        $category->id_parent = 3;
        $category->name[1] = $product->category_name;;
        $category->link_rewrite[1] = Tools::link_rewrite($product_xml->category_name);
        echo "<br />name of new category = $product->category_name <br /> <br />";
        $category->add();
        $category->id = Db::getInstance()->Insert_ID();
```

I have read somewhere here on stackoverflow that

> $category->id = Db::getInstance()->Insert_ID();

Should do the trick. Unfortunately, this returns always zero. Can someone see what I did wrong?

Edit: I am using prestashop version 1.6

**Edit: Answer:**
You don't need "Db::getInstance()->Insert_ID();" after $object->add() there is already an ID generated, the only thing you have to do is: echo $object->id; and you'll see your ID.

Best regards,

Evert Arends

Comment: Witch Prestashop version are you using ?

Comment: I am using version 1.6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prestashop already did this command in `classes/ObjectModel.php` method `add()`

```
// Get object id in database
$this->id = Db::getInstance()->Insert_ID();
```

When you use `add()` on an object this object automatically get its new id from database. So `$category->id` should already contain its new ID.

```
$category = new Category;
$category->active = 1;
$category->id_parent = 3;
$category->name[1] = $product->category_name;;
$category->link_rewrite[1] = Tools::link_rewrite($product_xml->category_name);
echo "<br />name of new category = $product->category_name <br /> <br />";
$category->add(); // Add will add the category to database and update category with its new id automatically
echo "category id = ".$category->id; // will show the category id.
```

Comment: But why does it return 0? I am sorry if I get your answer wrong, not a native speaker.

Comment: Because Prestashop already retrieved the last ID via `Insert_ID`. This method can be used only once per add.

Comment: aaand now I get it, thanks for your help, I will edit my question with this information. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
Last Inserted Id:

      echo $category->id;
```